# i am trying to run xmppclient app in android but it is showing "XMPPClient is not responding " error at run time

Tags: android

It's already implemented code & I am trying run the same code which is available on this link.
 http://davanum.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/updated-xmpp-client-for-android/

when I fill the parameters in dialog box like host name,port,service,username & password as
 talk.google.com, 5222, gmail.com, mygmailid without(@gmail.com),& password respt.
after that when i click on OK button, after some time it displays,XMPPClient is not responding, error on emulator.

please help me.

Comment: I am able to install and test XMPP Client with Android 1.6 
I got similar issue only when I misspelled host. Also, when proxy settings not properly set.
I think problem occurs when app is not able to connect to Internet or login.

Comment: I am using Android 1.5. My system has a open connection(no proxy & firewall). Please tell me what should I do? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, just glancing through the code my first thought is that you need to put any sort of blocking IO in a separate thread. Granted I only glanced through it quickly but if you mis-spell a hostname or something like that and the UI thread is blocked waiting for a socket timeout, that can definitely lead to ANR messages popping up.